# Hosted network on Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-hotspot

I've a new modul named  Qualcomm Atheros  QCNFA364A. And I've trying to get a hosted network activate without  any success so far! 
here what I've done:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MYONE key=12345678

The hosted network mode has been set to allow.
->The SSID of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
The user key passphrase of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
->The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

SO I've updated the driver using 2018 version:[image]

but still no change !

All Networks adapter active  including Microsoft Virtual Adapter:

[image]

```
ntsh wlan show drivers output is as follow:
```

[image]

Yes I can see that hosted adapter aren't supported.

My issue is whydoes the hotspot functionality of windows work fine, for the hardware is supporting the hotspot functionality ?

Does anybody had any hint ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: `Hosted network supported  : No` this is pretty self-explanatory. BTW, you've highlighted the wrong device on the device manage screenshot, hosted network specific one should be `Virtual WiFi Miniport` on supported system.

Comment: Now not that sure about the newer MS naming, but got the H/W clue for you: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Wireless_adapters/Chipset_table so check for better driver

Answer (score 0):

The "hosted networks" style soft AP is no longer supported. But it has been replaced by similar features in the new Wi-Fi Direct support on Windows, which is supported by those updated drivers. It doesn't look like you can just enable it with a `netsh` command, but need a little program to enable it.

The whole thing is now called "Wi-Fi Direct Legacy AP Mode" and there is sample code for a program that enables this here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirectLegacyAP

If you don't want to rebuild it yourself, you can grab some pre-built binaries from here: https://github.com/govert/WiFiDirectLegacyAPDemo/releases/tag/v1.0